# Password hashing inquiry

Tags: security, web, hash

I saw this https://youtu.be/8ZtInClXe1Q video today and it got me thinking.
If salted hashing implementation looks like this:
To Store a Password

Generate a long random salt using a CSPRNG.
Prepend the salt to the password and hash it with a standard password hashing function like Argon2, bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2.
Save both the salt and the hash in the user's database record.

To Validate a Password

Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
Prepend the salt to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the password is incorrect.

Basically u are storing the salt right there with a hashed password. If someone has inside access to this data table cant they reverse engineer the password the same way that it is validated?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a practical programming problem. It might be more suited for [security.se]

Answer (score 1):

No. Hash functions are designed to be one-way. You can't use the salt to reverse a hash.

Using different salts for different entries is a defence against [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).